# Showing specific columns in a dataframe based on list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, sorting

I have the following data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Sally', 'Fred', 'Tim'],
               'Random Text - Amish': [1,1,1], 
               'Text is Random - Matt': [1,0,1], 
               'More Random Text - Luke': [1,0,0],
               'OMG this text is random - Phil': [0,0,1], 
               })
```

I am looking to give a list and display the relevant columns based on the list. For example if I supplied `list = ['Amish', 'Luke']` it would show only those columns. The real data frame is very big so I will need to provide it with a list rather than manually specifying which columns.

Comment: Why did you not write some code which does this?

Comment: Hi mkrieger, because i didn't know the code. Im still learning and realize i need to really start learning my list comprehension. Hoping ill get there one day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
l = ['Amish', 'Luke']
columns = [c for c in df.columns for word in l if word in c]
df[columns]
```

The output is:

```
   Random Text - Amish  More Random Text - Luke
0                    1                        1
1                    1                        0
2                    1                        0
```

Comment: Looks like i need to brush up on my list comprehension. Thanks Rakesh and Roy2012

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.endswith` on `df.columns`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Sally', 'Fred', 'Tim'],
               'Random Text - Amish': [1,1,1], 
               'Text is Random - Matt': [1,0,1], 
               'More Random Text - Luke': [1,0,0],
               'OMG this text is random - Phil': [0,0,1], 
               })
lst = ('Amish', 'Luke')
ndf = df[[c for c in df.columns if c.endswith(lst)]]
print(ndf)
```

**Output:**

```
   Random Text - Amish  More Random Text - Luke
0                    1                        1
1                    1                        0
2                    1                        0
```